# Geometric progression, min $x^n > 100$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Suppose $x$ is a positive real number such that $\{x\}, [x]$ and $x$ are in a geometric progression. Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $x^n > 100$. (Here $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$ and $\{x\} = x - [x]$.)

**Attempt:** Let ${x}=a, [x]=ar, x=ar^2$.
$a+ar=ar^2$
$r^2-r-1=0$
$r=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$
Now,
$0\leq {x}<1$
$0\leq ar<r$
$0\leq [x]<1.61$
So, $[x]=0,1$
So, $x=r[x]=0,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$
$x$ is positive, so $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$
$x^n>100$
Thus, $n=10$

I'm right?

Comment: If you put double backslashes in your MathJax it makes a line feed and your equations do not run together.  That makes it much easier to read.  You lost the braces on $x$ when you defined $\{x\}=a$.  You need to escape them with one backslash each using \{x\}=a

Comment: You must have $x \gt 1$ if the powers are to increase, so $\lfloor x \rfloor =1$

Comment: Should not it be $a-ar=ar^2$?

Comment: Could you please put some *punctuation* or spaces or line breaks or *something* between your expressions. "$ar^2.a+ar = ar^2r^2 -r-1=0r=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$" looks nonsensiclal (what doe a decimal point in $ar^2.a$ mean?) and false.  (Clearly $0r = 0$ and so $ar^4 - r- 1 = 0 = \frac {1+\sqrt 5}2$ is not true.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lfloor x \rfloor =1$ as already shown (in comments). Let $x=1+y$

Let the three numbers be $\{y, 1, 1+y\}$. Then $y\times(1+y) = 1^2=1$. Solving this, we get $y = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4}}{2}$. Since $y\in[0,1]$, $y=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2} \simeq 0.6180 = \phi-1$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

Thus the numbers in geometric progression are $\{\phi-1, 1, \phi\}$=$\{\phi', 1, \phi\}$ where $\phi'=\phi-1=\frac{1}{\phi}$ is also known as the conjugate of the golden ratio

Now, $\phi^{10}$ crosses 100 for the first time. So the required $n=10$

See [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/GoldenRatio.shtml) for more information on the golden ratio